# In SQL Server does execution moves to next statement if the first statement throws the error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a SP that contains multiple update and insert queries.  If any of the query gives the error, does execution move to next statement?  For example,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test()
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES (1, 2, 3)
    UPDATE SomeTable SET X = 4 WHERE Y = 5
END
```

In above example, if INSERT statement throws the error, would execution move to next UPDATE statement?

Comment: Sometimes. Look at XACT_ABORT.

Comment: "It depends". Errors can do any of the following connection-termination, scope-abortion. statement-termination and batch-abortion. Not always intuitive to predict what category a particular error is in. See [Error Handling in SQL 2000 – a Background](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html)

Comment: @ta.speot.is I think XACT_ABORT OFF|ON would only apply to batches.

Comment: @ConradFrix I think it's more general purpose. See http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/20/Use-Caution-with-Explicit-Transactions-in-Stored-Procedures.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is I'm finding this hard to reason about. Can you think of case were if `INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES (1, 2, 3)` raised an exception the setting for `XACT_ABORT` caused `UPDATE SomeTable SET X = 4 WHERE Y = 5` to execute

Comment: @ConradFrix If it's OFF. See the examples as to what the effects of having this setting on or off are: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is the examples in that article are in a Batch. When I tried  something similar inside an SP. It didn't have the same effect when SETTING XACT_ABORT OFF in a proc, proc creation script or test to the proc. Are you able to observe an effect of XACT_ABORT OFF to a stored proc?

Comment: @ConradFrix I'll try as well, when I have some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the [error severity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx). From severity 19 and up, the batch gets aborted:

> Indicates that a nonconfigurable Database Engine limit has been
>   exceeded and the current batch process has been terminated. Error
>   messages with a severity level of 19 or higher stop the execution of
>   the current batch.

However note that if the code above runs within a `BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH` block (or is called from such a block) then errors with severity 10-18 cause the control flow to jump to the catch block (which is *not* the same as saying that the execution got aborted) and thus the next statement will **not** be executed.

In addition the [`XACT_ABORT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) setting also causes the current transaction to rollback *and* the current batch to abort.

If you want a template for how to write solid stored procedures code, see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/)

Comment: Pls refer to [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html) for error handling as per SQL Server 2005